# Login script for my website using PHP script

Tags: php, http, authentication

I wanted to use HTTP Authentication to create restrict to my website. I have written .htaccess file in my www directory, and now i wanted to create a htpasswd.php file to create a password and username. and i have to save it in a directory that cannot be accessible. Does anyone knows how to create htpasswd.php script for login and ???

I have this already:

```
<?php
// Password to be encrypted for a .htpasswd file
   $clearTextPassword = 'some password';

// Encrypt password
$password = crypt($clearTextPassword, base64_encode($clearTextPassword));

// Print encrypted password
echo $password;
?>
```

any help would be really appreciated. thx in advance

Comment: If you want to user HTTP auth and control it from PHP, you don't need to do anything with .htaccess - this would let Apache handle the auth. Take any auth-related config out of your .htaccess, and have a look at the basic example here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: I am not really sure how this gonna work. how should i take auth-related config out of my .htaccess??!! you said i don't need to do anything about the .htaccess???

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow instructions from below link

http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

make sure you will require absolute path to you .htpasswd file

you can get it by `echo __FILE__;`

Comment: how should i be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, if you want to do HTTP with PHP you follow this http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php, example #2
here important varilable is $realm that is checked for authentication you can generate it for as per requirements for timed expiration, like $realm = date('Ymd') will make it available only for same day